# Image coming with 0 bytes on download

Tags: php, download

I'm trying to download a image in php, the download is completed but the image is coming to me with 0 bytes.

```
<?php
$array = array("12345" => "guarana.jpg");

    $titulo = "Aula 17 - Download de arquivo";

    $idArquivo = $_GET['id'];
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=refri.jpg");

//the image is in the folder arquivos/guarana.jpg
        readfile("../arquivos/".$array[$idArquivo]);
```

I'm trying to download the img with the URL `http://localhost/DevMedia/PHP/app/download/index.php?id=12345`

Comment: Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` on top.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked ! What these two function do, in fact ?

Comment: They likely just add error message instead of the image file to the download. Now go open the JPEG in a text editor.